# How to resolve Oozie error : JA009: Cannot initialize Cluster.check configuration for mapreduce.framework.name

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I have been using oozie to schedule spark jobs.
Trying to deploy a spark job in 2.x cluster using spark action available in Oozie.

In my job.properties, I have the following

```
`nameNode=hdfs://hostname:8020
 jobTracker=hostname:8050
 master=yarn-cluster
 queueName=default
 oozie.use.system.libpath=true`
```

When i submit the oozie job, i have been receiving this error

Error:

ErrorCode [JA009], Message **[JA009: Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses.]
org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutorException: JA009: Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses.**
        at org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutor.convertExceptionHelper(ActionExecutor.java:457)

What am I doing wrong here ? Any thing to be changed in properties file ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting same error JA009 and in my case namenode was running in safemode so after leaving safemode it was able to initialize the cluster and i was able to submit the oozie job.

You can also refer following oozie error codes list.
https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.1.0/oozie-default.xml